# Data Transfer Between Sibling Components in Angular

Tags: angular, input, output, data-transfer, siblings

I have two sibling components and a parent components. I want to transfer array data in child-two to child-one.

**parent.component.html**

```
<child-one (employees)="employeesFromChild"></child-one>
<child-two (outputFromChild)="getEmployees($event)"></child-two>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
employeesFromChild!: Employee[];
getEmployees(event: Employee[]){
this.employeesFromChild = event;
}
```

**child-one.component.ts**

```
@Input() employees!: Employee[];
ngOnInit(){
 console.log(this.employees)
}
```

**child-two.component.ts**

```
selectedData: Employee[] = [
 {firstName: 'Max', lastName: 'Arnold', age: '25'},
 {firstName: 'Betty', lastName: 'Arnold', age: '22'},
 {firstName: 'Mark', lastName: 'Arnold', age: '20'},
];
@Output() outputFromChild: EventEmitter<Employee[]> = new EventEmitter<Employee[]>();
ngOnInit(){
this.outputFromChild.emit(this.selectedData);
}
```

I am getting undefined result in child-one when I console.log(this.employees). How can I fix it?

Comment: the ngOnInit() of your parent component will be called first. Then the one of the child. It might work using ngAfterViewInit() in the parent and ngOnInit() in child-two. 

Furthermore I would suggest formatting your question, that makes it easier to answer it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a square bracket instead of a round bracket in the child-one employees variable.

Square brackets are used for **Input** type event and Round brackets are used for **output** type event.

```
<child-one [employees]="employeesFromChild"></child-one>
<child-two (outputFromChild)="getEmployees($event)"></child-two>
```

And change **child-one.component.ts** life cycle hook to **ngOnChanges** instead of **ngOnInit**